# add a name value pair to posted data for joomla to consume and insert into DB

Tags: php, sql, joomla

I'm trying to use the Joomla framework to make a create in the main content table.[http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_the_JTable_class] This works fine except that some data comes from posted variables and some from logic that happens when a file is uploaded moments before (store the random image name of a jpg)

$data=&JRequest::get('post');

this takes a ref to the posted values and I want to add to this Array or Object my field. The code I have makes the new record but the column images, doesnt get my string inserted.

I am trying to do something like`$data=&JRequest::get('post');
        $newdata=(array)$data;
        array_push($newdata,"images"=>"Dog");`

i make newdata as data is a ref to the posted variables and i suspect wont there fore allow me to add values to $data.
I'm a flash guy normally not a php and my knowledge is letting me down here.

Thanks for any help

Comment: what are you getting form $data=&JRequest::get('post'); ? The return from &JRequest::get('post'); is array for not?

Comment: $data['images']="dogs";

This seems to work for me, thanks for your help mahadeb. I think it was an Array or stdObject not sure.

Comment: You are most welcome. After all we are for each other :)

Comment: GOT THE ARRAY WITH THE EXTRA VALUE,  it still isnt adding anything to the db now, though the record gets created. I would like to use my normal SQL to do the insert if it were not for the useful line 

$listing_id = $table->id;

The reason I need this line is to get the id, as I do a further insert into another table which needs to reference this table. If anyone knows how to retrieve the current inserted record ID number as this method does then I can use the regular SQL to do the insert. To get the ID you NEED to do the store.

Comment: I'm sure I'm doing this all wrong.

The steps are 
1 upload image to server and note the path
2 insert the record in 'content' table with the image path just generated
3 Insert a new record ref to the record just created.

Comment: yes - perfect thanks ! getting close now...does this respect each unique db connection so if there are multiple users doing inserts at the same time...

Comment: yes, this will return respect of each unique DB connection

Comment: Thanks very much you are most helpful and I now am progressing again.

Answer (score 1):

Right, first thing:

```
$data=&JRequest::get('post');
```

$data is an array, you do not have to cast it. To add another element to the array as described in the comments do this:

```
$data['images'] = 'cats';
```

If you are using normal SQL to do the insert then you would do something like this to get the last inserted id e.g. the id of the row you just inserted:

```
$db = $this->getDBO();
$query = 'Some sql';
$db->setQuery($query);
if (!$db->query()) {
  JError::raiseWarning(100, 'Insert failed - '.$db->getErrorMsg());
}
$id = $db->insertid();
```

If you are developing in Joomla I suggest you use the db functions provided to you rather than mysql_insert_id();

**[EDIT]**

If you want to use store then you can get the last inserted id like so:

```
$row->bind($data);
$row->check();
$row->store();
$lastId = $row->id;
```

Comment: Hi - I wanted to use store as its the J framework and a lot cleaner and does the field cleanup etc but it just didn't work for me. Come to think of it it was also not submitting this field so it probably did work and now I have fixed this array it should start to be ok again. Thanks for your answer.